# Is there a name for a function of () => A?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm exploring the random generation of values and I was wondering if a pattern/name already exists for concept. I have a function (and trait) whose signature is the following

```
trait Generator[A] { // good name?
  def generate: A

  // alternatively () => A
}
```

It resembles how the random number generator works.

```
val rng = new util.Random

val randInt = rng.nextInt
```

Should I be calling mine `nextWidget` instead of generate?

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but `nextInt` is not a function (whether in [Scala](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html) or in [functional programming](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/FPiS_meap_ch01.pdf)).

Comment: For what it's worth, [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) has an excellent treatment of random number generators in FP/Scala -- I'd strongly suggest reading that.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup: right, but eta expansion allows you to treat it as one more or less transparently.

Comment: @TravisBrown And thus "pedantic". :) The more important point is in relation to the FP notion of a function (since the FP tag is present) -- if `generate` returns different values on separate calls, it's not functional. There *are* functional patterns for dealing with such situations, though.

Comment: I guess I don't quite follow. Maybe my current understanding of the definition of `function` isn't tight enough. If it's not a function, what is it? I.e. what can I Google for to find out more?

Comment: @MarkCanlas: what Scala calls functions aren't necessarily "pure" functions—they can return different values for the same inputs or perform side effects. For example, you can turn `nextInt` into something called a `Function0`, but it'll still be impure.

Comment: @MarkCanlas In functional programming, `nextInt` would not have internal state. Instead, it would take the "current" seed as an argument and return both the "next" seed and the random number corresponding to the given seed. The State monad generalizes this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This depends entirely on the semantics of the operation. You can think of `util.Random` as a source of random values, and in that context names like `nextInt` make sense. If the method was reading from a file or database, I'd find a name like `nextFoo` a little misleading, and would probably prefer something like `loadFoo`. In other contexts `getFoo` or `generateFoo` or `initFoo` or `createFoo` might make more sense.

Three quick side notes:

If your method has side effects (like e.g. `Random.nextInt()`), it's good to follow convention and write it as `def generate(): Whatever` (note the parentheses). The eta-expanded function will be a `() => Whatever` either way.

It's also worth noting that `() => A` is syntactic sugar for `Function0[A]`, and these are sometimes called "nullary functions".

Lastly: I know `def generate[A]: A` may just be an example, but if not, you might want to think of ways you can constrain the type `A`. `def generate[A]: A` says "tell me any type at all and I'll give you a value of that type",  which is impossible to implement in a useful way.

Comment: It's part of a trait of [A], so the type parameter wouldn't be so local. I see what you're saying though. Maybe I will edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Cool, then you're safe (but note that in that case you still don't want the method to be parametrized, because its `A` would just shadow the trait's type parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Some might call that an Enumerator or Iterator: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote-Duality

```
new Iterator[A]{
    def hasNext: Boolean = true
    def next(): A = ???
}
```

Some people might call it a Supplier: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html

Or maybe just a getter:

```
trait Getter[A] {
    def get(): A
}
```

Others a builder, factory, provider, or... generator.  Context is king here.  I would use what best describes its intended implementation.